# The INSERT statement conflicted

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, linq-to-sql

My project in C# Winforms 2010 and use SQL Server express and Linq-to-SQL. My project get me exception:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'*

and when I ran this query:

```
SELECT name, definition
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE name = 'CK_BarCode_Num'"
```

the output shows the definition of:

```
Name: CK_BarCode_Num    
Definition: (datalength([BarCode_Num])=(13))"
```

but in `TBL_Cards` in database, type of `BarCode_Num` is `varchar(100)` and in code behind, I declare `int` for type of `BarCode_Num`.

I don't know where is set `datalength([BarCode_Num])=(13)`?

Comment: BarCode_Num in code should be a string

Comment: i do set this in code, get me exception:"The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'.
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The check constraint is saying that whatever you insert into `Barcode_Num` has to be exactly 13 characters long.

If you're trying to insert something that isn't 13 characters long, I'd recommend you consult the documentation for your database (or talk to whoever set it up) to understand *why* this constraint has been applied.

We'll not be able to answer that for you, and I wouldn't recommend altering the check constraint without understanding why it exists in the first place.

---

[`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

> Returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression.

For `varchar`, the number of bytes used corresponds 1-1 with the number of characters. For `nvarchar` you would need to divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

The data type is separate from any check constraints you have defined. You can modify the check constraint following these instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191273.aspx

Otherwise, you can perform the data validation in your own code - Linq to SQL won't enforce it on the entity, but will throw a SqlException when you attempt to perform an insert that violates the constraint.

Comment: `!!!!true == true;` ... Just saying, you could probably do without the excessive exclamation marks.